# Maximum summation of i*A[i] in an array

Tags: arrays

Given an array, you can only ROTATE the array as many times you want. Return the maximum of summation of (i*A[i]). Can anyone tell me the approach to solve this question ?

Comment: You surely have some idea to approach this, right? "just try everything" would be an obvious first attempt.

Comment: I don't know how to go ahead with this question as I heard this from somewhere. I couldn't find any approach.

Comment: Any approach? "just try all rotations" is an approach. Not the best one obviously.. If you google literally that question, you find a nice O(n log n) approach, so that's something.